# select limited rows from large records

Tags: php, laravel

I have more than 1000 records from a function call and using `take()` I got first 10 records as follows,

```
$users = Users::GetActivatedUsers()->take(10)->get();
```

so, I want to go through all of records (1000 or above) 10 by 10. I have done following part for it. but it is only going with first 10 records only. so how can I get rest of records 10 by 10

```
$count = $users->count();

if (!empty($users) && ($count > 0)){

// operation in this function

}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `chunk` function of the Query Builder to give you chunks in the size you would like and you can pass a callback to do what you would like with the returned chunks:

```
Kit::GetActivatedUsers()->chunk(10, function ($chunk) {
    foreach ($chunk as $user) {
        ...
    }
});
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Queries - Chunking Results](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#chunking-results) `chunk`